# Excel VBA Scraping li tags with the same class name

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape li tags that shares the same class name
the HTML cods looks like this:

```html
<ul class="top-section-list" data-selenium="highlightList">    
                <li class="top-section-list-item">sample text# 1</li>           
                <li class="top-section-list-item">sample text# 2</li>            
                <li class="top-section-list-item">sample text# 3</li>           
                <li class="top-section-list-item">sample text# 4</li>            
                <li class="top-section-list-item">sample text# 5</li>     
        </ul>
```

Here is my VBA Code that can only Scrapes the first listed item, not the rest of them.

```
    Sub GetData()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim itemEle As Object
    Dim data As String
    Dim y As Integer

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1312545-REG/fujifilm_16550643_instax_mini_9_instant.html"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    For Each itemEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("top-section-list")
    data = itemEle.getElementsByTagName("li")(0).innerText

    Next
    Range("A1").Value = data
End Sub
```

it only writes to cells A1: "sample text# 1"
how can i have all the tags to be written to cell A1?
desired result would be cell A1:
sample text# 1
sample text# 2
sample text# 3
sample text# 4
sample text# 5

Thanks!

Comment: How does `data = Range("A1").Value` write the *data* string value **into** cell A1?

Comment: It should be the other way around, i got confused

Comment: Okay, get back to you soon.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.querySelectorAll` and loop over the nodeList returned

CSS selector to use is

```
ul.top-section-list li
```

---

**VBA Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer, nodeList As Object, currentItem As Long, outputString As String
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1312545-REG/fujifilm_16550643_instax_mini_9_instant.html"

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set nodeList = objIE.document.querySelectorAll("ul.top-section-list li")
    With ActiveSheet                             '<== use actual sheet name
        For currentItem = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
            outputString = outputString & Chr$(32) & nodeList.item(currentItem).innerText
        Next currentItem
        .Cells(1, 1) = Trim$(outputString)
    End With
    'ObjIE.Quit
End Sub
```

---

CSS query:

[image: CSS selector query] [Try it](http://try.jsoup.org/~Z-jWbWSbHhQOpQ9KYsc_vNmNHKA)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way could be something like:

```
Dim data As String
Dim elem as object

data = ""
For Each elem In html.getElementsByClassName("top-section-list")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")
    data = data & " " & elem.innerText
Next elem
[A1] = data
```

Output:

```
 sample text# 1 sample text# 2 sample text# 3 sample text# 4 sample text# 5
```

Now, give this a shot:

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, data As String

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1312545-REG/fujifilm_16550643_instax_mini_9_instant.html"
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    data = ""

    For Each elem In html.getElementsByClassName("top-section-list")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")
        data = data & " " & elem.innerText
    Next elem

    Range("A1").Value = data

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

I've tried to refine your code to give a slightly pleasant look.

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

One more thing: as Jeeped pointed out, if you get a trailing space then you can try something like `Range("A1").Value = Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(data))`

Comment: Your example output shows a space character (e.g. Chr(32)) as a delimiter but your code is not adding one.

Comment: Yes, that looks appropriate but without `Trim(data)` you will still have a leading space character. Since I was using a linefeed as a delimiter, I chose `Mid(data, 2)` instead.

Comment: Hi Shahin, i'm getting "object doesn't support this method.. i have edited my original post to show the exact website so this way you can test it. thank you for all the help

Comment: @rkrox907 - It seems Shahin substituted `html` for `objIE.document`. Other than that, the code looks like it should work.

Comment: See the edit. Btw, do you know what reference to add to the library?

Comment: To get them in separate lines in a single cell you can do something like `data = data & vbNewLine & elem.innerText` . Okay I'm done here.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the string values into the *data* string var with a vbLF delimiter.

```
dim data as string, i as long
data = vbNullString

with objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("top-section-list")(0)
    For i = 0 to .getElementsByTagName("li").Length - 1
        data = data & vblLF & .getElementsByTagName("li")(i).innerText
    Next
end with
Range("A1").Value = Mid(data, 2)  'write data INTO A1, not the other way around
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I tried your soulution. im getting "object doesn't support the property or method on line " For i = 0 to .getElementsByTagName("li").Count - 1"

Comment: I admit to writing the code off the top of my head; tbh, I don't have the time to set up or even locate an appropriate *someWebsite* for testing. Perhaps you can figure it out yourself; I know that the method at least is valid.

Comment: OK, it was supposed to be `.Length` not `.Count`.

Comment: yep now its working! with .Length TY! Is it possible to have each innerText in a separate line rather than all of them in one line?

Comment: That is what the `vbLF` does. It is a 'line-feed'. Try using Wrap Text format on A1.

Comment: Works great with the line break. thanks. the cods fails if i enter this address, https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1214161-REG/nikon_1559_d500_dslr_camera_body.html. it gives me what includes for free instated of the products highlight. how can i target "top-section-list-item" only?